# How to Base an IF date statement in Velocity Code?

Tags: java, velocity

I'm new to forum.
I've been playing around with some velocity code which relates to a feed that I'm using. I know there is an issue with my Merge field.

Essentially I only want to display dates before a variable date (Today) although my statement doesn't throw an error I get 2020 date included in the returned document and in this document I have a table which will fill all rows based on the condition is met Final end date is < $today.

```
$!{columns.put("Finalenddate","Final end date")}
#set($date = $conversionTool.parseDate($record.Finalenddate,"dd/MM/yyyy"))
@before-row#if($date1.before($today))
@after-row#end
```

All of these are merge fields.

I've a little unsure where I have gone wrong as they seem to be fine (I've got other entries in the table eg:

```
«@before-row#foreach($record in $data)» 
«@before-row#if($date.before($today))»
«$record.ReviewStatus»
«@after-row#end» 
«@after-row#end»
```

If this condition is met in the growing table then they will be populated and the other records will be filled in the other columns.

Thanks for your help in advanced.